# How can I insert OpenXML-Word files into another document programmatically in Word 2003

Tags: ms-word, vsto, openxml

I need to insert an OpenXML Word document into another document in Word 2003 inside a VSTO 2005 customization.

With the old WordML (2003) documents I used Selection.InsertXML() for this, but OpenXML or the flat XML format (Flat OPC) of it does not work with this method in Word 2003 even if the compatiblity pack is installed (no surprise).

What options do I have to accomplish this?

Ernst

Answer (score 0):

If the two file formats are incompatible with .InsertXML(), possibly try using VSTO to copy from the OpenXML document and paste into the WordML document. Hopefully the basic formatting of the document structure is retained after that operation.

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model (which VSTO extends) has the Range.InsertFile method. You can use that to bring in the content of another Word document.